# Is i7-940XM compatible with rPGA989 socket?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7, sockets

Is the Intel i7-940XM compatible with a rPGA989 socket?
My laptop is a ASUS K52JT with a Pentium P6200 processor.
Can I replace it with i7-940XM?

If I can, at which frequencies can I run it?
The cpu-world website says that this socket can apply up to 2.8 GHz, but i7-940XM can produce 3.33 GHz.
Does this mean that I need to choose a processor up to 2.8 GHz maximum?

Comment: How did you determine that your laptop uses rPGA989? Intel ARK says [both](https://ark.intel.com/products/43127/Intel-Core-i7-940XM-Processor-Extreme-Edition-8M-Cache-2-13-GHz-) [CPUs](https://ark.intel.com/products/50176/Intel-Pentium-Processor-P6200-3M-Cache-2-13-GHz-) are PGA988.

Comment: @grawity I read this on the my socket.  There written exactly rPGA989, not rPGA988.

Comment: We also need your motherboard to answer.

Comment: "Does this mean that I need to choose a processor up to 2.8 GHz maximum?" No, that part just means that the fastest compatible CPU **at the time of writing** was 2.8GHz. Not that that is any kind of hard limit.  @K7AAY answer though might point at a hard limit due to heat dissipation and power supply to the socket. *might*.  And If you remove the motherboard from the laptop case and supply the CPU with plenty cooling the heat dissipation might actually also be solved. The next question would be if enough power can be supplied to the socket without VRM overheating. Also no longer portable.

Comment: Lots of ifs. Laptop CPU upgrading is rare enough that system which allow it (or make it easy) often explicitly mention this.

Comment: @Vladimir This is way too late, but for historical record : The Socket rPGA 989 is a superset socket which contains the union of the rPGA 988A and 988B holes. It supports both 988A and 988B, that is its very purpose of existence. Source (esp second page) is https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7F1-1773456-7_SOCKETS_RPGA989_RPGA988%7F0611%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_1-1773456-7_SOCKETS_RPGA989_RPGA988_0611.pdf%7FN-A

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad idea.

Whether it would fit or not, your laptop was very carefully designed around the [P6200](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel%20Pentium%20P6200%20%40%202.13GHz&id=1120) processor, which uses at most, 35 watts. The [CPU you want to change to](http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/CPUs/Intel/Core_i7_Mobile_Extreme_Edition/i7-940XM.html) is a [55 watt processor](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel%20Core%20i7-940XM%20%40%202.13GHz&id=865), and '[power consumption of up to 55 Watt (TDP) is quite high for a laptop CPU](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Core-i7-940XM-Notebook-Processor.31541.0.html)'. Increasing the power consumption by 57% will likely result in overheating, unreliability, shutdown, and possible damage.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the Intel i7-940XM compatible with a rPGA989 socket?

The Intel i7-940XM is a PGA989 processor.  This processor uses a pin grid array, which means, the processor is soldered to the motherboard.  This means the processor was NOT designed to be removed by the end user.

> My laptop is an ASUS K52JT with a Pentium P6200 processor.

The Pentium P6200 is a PGA988 socket processor.    This processor uses a pin grid array, which means, the processor is soldered to the motherboard.  This means the processor was NOT designed to be removed by the end user.

> Can I replace it with i7-940XM?

The Intel i7-940XM appears compatible with your PGA988 socket.  However, compatibility is not guaranteed, as the motherboard's firmware must also support it.  **At the end of your day, while it might be compatible with the socket, your K52JT was not designed to run an Intel i7-940XM.**

So even if you were to remove your existing processor, in such a way, the motherboard still worked.  You would have to resolder the new processor, a processor that wasn't designed to work in the device you have, so compatibility isn't guaranteed.

> There are Socket G/rPGA 989 sockets that can take Socket G1/rPGA 988A or Socket G2/rPGA 988B packaged processors

Source: [Socket G1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_G1)

Comment: @Vladimir - I don’t answer questions submitted as a comment.  Your CPU is soldered to the motherboard.  It was not designed to be removed.